# change in the root folder in the terminal

Tags: shell, ssh, terminal, command, vagrant

My terminal used to display this whenever I was in the root folder on my terminal. [image: Original]

Now, it displays the [image: following].  I believe this has something to do with Vagrant, but I don't know how to get out of this state and back to my original terminal.

Answer (score 0):

check your `hostname` and your environment variable `$PS1`. It looks like it has changed somehow. Mac has probably the way how change hostname in graphical environment and it should be preferred way:

Open up **System Preferences**, go to **Sharing**, and change the computer name. Done!

---

Or from terminal:

```
sudo scutil --set HostName [NewHostNameHere]
```

Comment: None of those methods work, but if I write "exit" it says "logout" and Process Complete, but nothing really happens